# чекбокс, активация класса для всего рядка таблицы

Tags: html, jquery, css

есть таблица, одна из колонок таблицы чекбоксы, необходимо при выделении чекбокса бекграунд для всего рядка сделать красным.
Желательно на чистом CSS, но можно и через Jquery

Comment: через css вроде родитель не выбирается.

Comment: предоставьте ваш код, с которым проблемы

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. структура не была дана, предлагаю вот такой способ (без js/jq):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  background: #39A2AE;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
ul {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
li {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

section {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;  
  padding: 10px;
}
input:checked + li {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.2)
}
input:checked + li label {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.3)
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <input id="1-1" type="checkbox" />
  <li>    
    <label for="1-1"></label>
    <section>
     <span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </span>
      <span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </span>
      <span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </span>
    </section>    
  </li>
  <input id="1-2" type="checkbox" />
  <li>    
    <label for="1-2"></label>
    <section>
     <span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </span>
      <span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </span>
      <span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </span>
    </section>    
  </li>
  <input id="1-3" type="checkbox" />
  <li>    
    <label for="1-3"></label>
    <section>
     <span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </span>
      <span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </span>
      <span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </span>
    </section>    
  </li>
  <input id="1-4" type="checkbox" />
  <li>    
    <label for="1-4"></label>
    <section>
     <span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </span>
      <span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </span>
      <span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </span>
    </section>    
  </li>
  
</ul>
```